# Create a new dataframe from a existing dataframe by iterating through repeated string values in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im reading in data and storing it in a pandas dataframe. I want to cretae a new dataframe structure.

Where Columns A and B are string values and column C are numpy floats.

Current dataframe structure (df_1):

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell_1 | Metal_1 | 0.2 |
| Cell_1 | Metal_2 | 0.4 |
| Cell_1 | Metal_3 | 0.3 |
| Cell_1 | Metal_4 | 0.5 |
| Cell_2 | Metal_1 | 0.1 |
| Cell_2 | Metal_2 | 0.2 |
| Cell_2 | Metal_3 | 0.3 |
| Cell_2 | Metal_4 | 0.7 |

I want to iterate through the current dataframe (df_1) and make a new dataframe (df_2).

So Column B string values become the index, Column B vlaues become individual columns and column C become rows associated with both.

The intended dataframe (df_2) will look like this:

| Index | Cell_1 | Cell_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Metal_1 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| Metal_2 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| Metal_3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| Metal_4 | 0.5 | 0.7 |

I havent tried anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use a loop. just use the pivot method

```
df.pivot(columns='Column A', values='Column C', index='Column B')
```